# NodeJS - Can we update a populated subdocument from Mongoose?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Like I have a collection Authors . Now Authors Schema has a array containing Books Array which contains an array of Ids of related documents from a Books Collection.

Now in Mongoose if I populate Authors books array I get all the book documents . Now suppose the returned Author object is authorObj

And I do

```
authorObj.books[0].name = 'New Name'
```

and then call

```
authobj.save(function(err,detail){
if(!err)
  console.log("All Updated");
})
```

Will this update the Books Document and update its Name?

Comment: It depends on your schemas construction

Comment: first try it , then reply .

Answer (score 0):

No since Book Document of other schema, so you need to update using the Book Object in order the document.